# Script is just reading one element of both product name and price but isn't reading and writing all items. kindly review'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is there something wrong with my loop statements or have i got the wrong tag? but when i check len(containers) it gives me 20 which means i have got the tag right but when i try to use a selector like i used p.text and strong.text stored into a variable and then write it into a file i get just only one element for product_name and one for price. kindly review
Here is my script:

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen as Ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://laptopparts.ca/collections/types?q=Accessories'
Uclient = Ureq(my_url)
page_html = Uclient.read()
Uclient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"grid__item large--one-quarter medium-down--one-half"})

filename = "products.csv"

f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Title, Price\n"  

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:

    title_container = container.findAll("p")
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("strong")
    price = price_container[0].text


print("product_name " + product_name)
print("price " + price)

f.write(product_name.replace(",","|") + "," + price + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Can you access that address through some other means? Looks like there is a problem with it. Make sure it's reachable and your connection is OK.

Comment: @kabanus thanks that error was sorted out. as you said it was some problem with my connection. but my script is writing just one element into each header. can you tell me why that's happening? can you please check my tags in scripts and also on the link.?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a go. The below script should fetch you all the item titles and price and write those in a csv file accordingly. I tried to shake off some extraneous lines which made your script look horrible.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = urlopen('https://laptopparts.ca/collections/types?q=Accessories').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    writer.writerow(['Title','Price'])

    for container in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"large--one-quarter"}):
        title = container.find("p").text
        price = container.find("strong").text
        print(title,price)
        writer.writerow([title,price])
```